# Inserting a pdf as part of a slide

Tags: pdfpages

I would like to insert a page from another presentation (saved as pdf) into another presentation, but i don't want this page to occupy a whole slide, as i want to write something underneath.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: If you use `\includegraphics` then the size of the imported image becomes smaller. To avoid this, you can trim the unnecessary part of it. What do you think?

Comment: @Marienplatz But `\includegraphics` doesn't let you specify a page to include. Or does it? If not, then perhaps the best solution is to include the graphics using pdfTeX primitives. It's a bit tricky, but not *that* hard.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: `\includegraphics` has an optional key-value `page=<page number>`.

Comment: @Marienplatz: That's interesting. I see no mention of it in the documentation (`grfguide.pdf`), and I am unable to see it `graphicx.sty` either. But the option works! It's magic! Oh, wait … it's in `pdftex.def`, it seems. But where the heck is it documented?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I did not read the documentations but I got it from other answers on this site.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes this works \includegraphics [page=15,scale=0.45]{pic.pdf}

Comment: @DonutE.Knot Can you please proceed to make an answer to this Q as well.